# How to implement a badge counter on android hamburger menu icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-menu, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement a counter badge on the hamburger menu icon (i.e. not the other menu icons). Similar to the eBay app. as in..

[image: Ebay app badge counter]

Has anyone looked into this? Trying to figure out the cleanest way possible.

Comment: ya set textview in above the menu icon image..and set circle background

Comment: Can you ellaborate as the hamburger menu icon is embedded as part of the theme. So How do you change it?

Comment: It's not a duplicate as this about adding a badge on the hamburger menu icon specifically. Not other menu icons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its pretty simple to do with the `Toolbar Widget` you could follow below example to achieve that:

first create an `Oval shape`

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ff00"/>
</shape>
```

then create a `toolbar` widget as below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="?colorPrimary">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/openMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/badger"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|right|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/badge"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up removing the existing menu icon and setting a new one with the badge as above layout. Thanks

Comment: @k0sh Can you elaborate a bit more. I have tried your code and I just end up with two hamburger icons... :-/

Comment: @ban-geoengineering if you used above code, remove the programmatically setting of the hamburger icon.